# Could form values be preserved without using session scope?

Tags: session, jsf, icefaces

I have two pages having page one got datatable and a few LOV's.

When I navigate from page one to page two, could the values in LOV's and datatable pagination be preserved when I navigate back to page one from page two without using session scope?

If so how can I do this?

***Update 1***

I could see the following log when I run my application. May be I am missing something obvious!!

```
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value 2
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value false
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL' found, using default value false
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS' found, using default value org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH' found, using default value /faces/myFacesExtensionResource
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER' found, using default value true
4234 [ApplicationServerThread-0] INFO  org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig  - Starting up Tomahawk on the RI-JSF-Implementation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had with preserving form values after navigating back(request scope) is resolved using FullRedirectTrackPolicy.

Add the following in web.xml and add tomahawk-sandbox.jar to your project.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.redirectTracker.POLICY</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.custom.redirectTracker.policy.FullRedirectTrackPolicy</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

More information is available [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-503)

I couldn't resolve without redirect rules in faces-config.xml, there are a few errors.

Thanks @BalusC for providing information about t:saveState and to @user339637

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the MyFaces Tomahawk 's `<t:saveState>`  tag to save the so-called LOV in page 1.

If you use JSF2 , it seems that you can try view scope feature  .

> What is the View Scope ? View Scope
>   has been introduced in JSF 2.0 and
>   it's particularly useful when you are
>   editing some objects while staying in
>   the same page. In other words it's
>   something broader then request but
>   smaller then session, since this scope
>   terminates if you navigate to other
>   pages.

You can refer to http://www.mastertheboss.com/java-ee-16-articles/258-jsf-20-tutorial-on-jboss-as-part-1.html for the example of how to use view scope in JSF 2.

Comment: @user339637 Thanks for the response, in fact I am using JSF 1.1 with Icefaces 1.8.0. I tried using <t:saveState. I did as follows `<t:saveState id="saveCalcForm" value="#{bean}" />`, but for some reason state is not saved when I return back to first page. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I've already suggested the OP to use `t:saveState`, but it didn't work well with IceFaces somehow, so I deleted the answer and added the `icefaces` tag to the question.

Comment: I have added a few log entries of my application as Update 1

Comment: Are there any alternate to <t:saveState, some other way of saving state or any other mechanism?

Comment: Using h:inputHidden how can I retrieve values when I navigate back or using requestMap?

Comment: BalusC and other experts, could you please confirm  whether JSF 1.1 work with Tomahawk's t:saveState? Myfaces doc provide the following url http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_saveState.html I am desperately trying to make this work.

Comment: I managed to preserve the form values using <t:savestate>. The issue I was having was <redirect> rule in my faces-config.xml. Without redirect I was not able to navigate to my second page. To overcome this I used FullRedirectTrackPolicy in web.xml. Testing in progress, upon finishing I would post further details.